# Program hangs in debug when multiprocessing process opens another process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pycharm, pydev, python-multiprocessing

In a python program, a Process is opened using `multiprocessing.Process`. Then this process is creating a `Pool` in order to give it some work using the `map()` method.

When the program is normally run, all works as expected. However, when it is run in PyCharm debugger, the call to `Pool.map` never returns and program is locked.

The problem is demonstrated in the following simple example:

1) Code:

```
import multiprocessing

def inc(a):
    return a + 1;

def func():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    print("before map")
    res = p.map(inc, [1,4])  # ==> the method hangs in debug.
    print("after call map")
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print(res)

def main():
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func)
    p.start()
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

2) Output as expected when program is run:

```
before map
after call map
[2, 5]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

3) Output when program run in debugger - never completes:

```
pydev debugger: process 13792 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 173.4301.16)
before map
```

Is this just a very annoying debugging issue (maybe caused by debugger background threads?)? or is it a multiprocessing problem that might appear also in real run?

It should be mentioned that using only one of the subprocessing steps, meaning either just opening a `Process()`, or just using a `pool.map()`, causes no problems and could be debugged. The problem occurs only in the "nested" subrocessing, as described.

I am running PyCharm on a Windows 10 64 bit machine.

Comment: Got a similar problem in pycharm 2020. Any solutions you found?

Comment: Unfortunately not, @MichelePiccolini. But I did not look into the issue since.

Answer (score 1):

I just had similar problem and found out that I was having a break point placed inside the function that I was calling using the `map()` method. Removing this break point or ignoring break points resolved the problem for me. Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the cause of this, but I can say for my m1 mac, the hanging was caused by not explicitly setting the start method:

```
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```